# Has any professional mathematician ever attempted to solve the Riemann hypothesis using only number theory?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

I have often heard people saying that ''all attempts at solving the Riemann hypothesis using number theory have failed.'' But in the literature, i cannot find any failed ''purely number-theoretic'' attempted solution of the problem, at the professional level. Indeed, the failed proofs of de Branges and Xian Jin Li, for example, seem not to use any properties of properties of primes, Euler product etc. Even the recently reported progress https://phys.org/news/2019-05-mathematicians-revive-abandoned-approach-riemann.html seems not to use any properties of primes as well.

Combining this with Peter Sarnak's statement of 2018 that ''90 % of the proposed proofs of the RH received by the Annals only make use of the Euler product and never the functional equation,'' one is left wondering: **has there ever been any attempted solution of the the RH, at the professional level, that was purely number-theoretic ?**

NB: Here i am not considering Stiltjes legendary claimed proof via the Mertens function, since it was never seen by anyone.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as asked, but the very fact that you can't even *find* any attempts of such a proof is evidence for your first quoted statement. Pure number theory is so hopeless in approaching problems of RH sort that no one has ever gotten with it even close to anything that could be mistaken for a proof.

Comment: Deninger's ideas seem to include an Euler product. RMT has made attempts to include the primes, though outside of Ivic making an aside (quotations in original, seemingly his impression from Conrey's survey) that "The Riemann hypothesis is in the process of being proved" by such powerful methods, I don't think it's practitioners have ever seen it as a vehicle for an RH proof, but rather for more understanding of the $\zeta$-function (indeed, likely assuming RH along the way). OTOH, clearly neither of these is "using only number theory"...

Comment: Sarnak said 99%. http://heilbronn.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Sarnak-talk.pdf If accurate, that still leaves 1.5 proofs per year that do use the Euler product.... Anyway, you are correct that the recent Jensen approach (presumably) applies to linear combinations of Dirichlet L-functions also, where we of course know the zeros need not be on the critical line, and in that sense is not particularly "evidence" for RH (see page 7 of Sarnak's talk).

Comment: More explicitly, Deninger's work with his regularized determinant at least at one stage uses the "explicit formula", thus the logarithmic derivative of the $L$-function, ergo the Euler product. Perhaps I am misled (has anyone tried to generalize regularized determinants to linear combinations?), but I think this indicates an arithmetic presence. See Theorem 3.3 and Section 4 of http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01231885